# How to access values from array in different View Controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS platform.

I have created a User class with a shared instance:

```
class User {
    var Name: String
    var Email: String
    var Password: String
    var City: String
    var State: String
    var Zipcode: String
    var Country: String

    static var sharedUser: User?
}
```

... then I've created an array:

```
var userArray = [User.sharedUser]
```

in different View Controller to get the values.

Now I want to read the values from this `userArray` and want to assign to `textfield.text`.

What code should be written in a different view controller to access the class values from the array?

Comment: reformat your code, it is unreadable

Comment: why are you creating an array of User.sharedUser? It is just a single instance, not an array? Where do you set the value of sharedUser?

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, you have a static member of the User class as an instance of the User class which means this member is accessible anywhere without having to pass values around.

Since it's initialized to an Optional, I'm going to assume for this question you create an instance of the User class somewhere and assign it to this static variable somewhere.

Therefore, whenever you want to access this, whether it's in another class or a different View Controller like you're example stated, you can simply access the static member of this class to use its values for text fields.

```
User.sharedUser?.name
```

Based on your question, there's no need to create an array.